# Eclipse, remove override error

Tags: java, eclipse, error-reporting, overriding

I have overriden a controller class in a java projects in order to add an interceptor,
I would like to know if there is anyway I can remove the "error" showing up in Eclipse:

> The type CRUD is already defined

I don't think the code will help much but there you go:

```
package controllers;

    public abstract class CRUD extends Controller {
```

Comment: give the code that shows this error

Comment: Well basically I'm just creating a class that has the same name as an existing class to override it.

Comment: Controller? Interceptor? We have no idea what these things mean in your context.

Comment: @mnml: You can't override a **class**.  You can extend a class and thus override the parent class' methods, but you cannot create a class with the same fully-qualified name.  This is not a warning you're seeing, it's a (fatal!) compilation error.

Comment: I can, if I use the same class name, the framework I'm using takes the controller located in my project repository instead of the one located in the module repository.

Comment: project repository, module repository - stop using terms that are relevant to your context and are totally irrelevant out of it. Tell us the framework, the setup, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was removed after a rebuild of the eclipse project.

Answer (score 2):

From Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings, find your case and choose "Ignore" from the drop down menu

Answer (score 0):

From top of my head:

Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Name shadowing and conflicts -> alter the settings there per your likes.

The same can be done for a particular project only, by enabling project specific compiler settings in project properties (Java Compiler section).